# TCPDF ERROR joomla virtuemart does not create the invoice

Tags: joomla, tcpdf, virtuemart

I use joomla 3.9.6, virtuemart 3.4.2, and tcpdf 1.0.7 
When i try to view the invoice(pdf) or when i change order status to confirmed i get the TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: \vmorders\invoices\invoice_190522TIXG01.pdf

i already have created the folders vmorders\invoices and gave it the proper permissions. (the site runs locally with wamp)

Php Error log

```
[22-May-2019 16:11:21 UTC] PHP Warning: fopen(): remote host file access not supported, file://\vmorders\invoices\invoice_190522TIXG01.pdf in C:\wamp64\www\byzantinemusic\libraries\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php on line 1854
```

Comment: check your permissions

Comment: I have put all users to full control. The error keeps showing!

Comment: Do you mean you have set everything to 777?

Comment: I use windows 10. I think that full control is equivalent to chmod 777 (linux)

Comment: i changed "tcpdf_static.php" line 1850 to $filename = $filename; instead of $filename = 'file://'.$filename;. invoice is created successfully but not inside wamp folder. It is created in root c:\

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the solution. Edit "libraries\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php". At line 1850 remove code

```
$filename = 'file://'.$filename;
```

and substitute with this

```
$absPath = getcwd(); 
            $filename =  str_replace("\\administrator","",$absPath) .$filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Virtuemart 3.6.10:

Edit "libraries\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_static.php".

At line 1817 remove code:

```
$filename = 'file://'.$filename;
```

and replace with:

```
    $filename = $filename;
    $absPath = getcwd(); 
    $filename =  str_replace("\\administrator","",$absPath)."/".$filename;
```

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development and happy to share your insights, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.